# Get Data from JSON String

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm unable to successfully get data from the JSON string below. Using JavaScript, I'm able to alert the full string [ alert(data); ] but I'm unable to get only the first name.

Can someone please help?

```
var data = {
    "name": [
        "Enid Norgard",
        "Cassie Durrett",
        "Josephine Ervin"
    ],
    "email": [
        "TheWoozyGamer@gmail.com",
        "TheHabitualGamer@gmail.com",
        "TheUptightGamer@gmail.com"
    ],
    "role": [
        "Gamer",
        "Team Leader",
        "Player"
    ],
    "emp_id": [
        "50",
        "408",
        "520"
    ],
    "id": [
        "234",
        "444",
        "235"
    ]
}
```

Comment: The first name is in `data.name[0]`

Comment: I get the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: this works -> data.name[0] , but i think your real codde is a different one , please provide the real code

Comment: This question lies in its presentation of existing code. `data` should be wrapped in quotes as in "real life" it is a string, as the accepted answer indicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you have a string(because when you use alert the complete text is shown, if it was a object then `[Object object]` would have shown), first you need to parse it using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
var t = JSON.parse(data)
alert(t.name[0])
```

Note: Old browsers like IE8 which does not have native support for JSON you have to add a library like [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to add JSON support

Comment: @Paul not `alert({"hello":"world"}) `

Comment: JSON.parse solved the issue as I wasn't parsing the string. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use the following code

```
alert(data.name[0]);
```

Comment: I get the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: I think you didn't provide your real code, check a running version here: http://jsfiddle.net/qzv6B/

Answer (score 1):

```
    //sample code
    var json = '{"result":true,"count":1}',
    obj = JSON.parse(json);
    alert(obj.count);
```

For the browsers that don't you can implement it using json2.js.
Most browsers support JSON.parse(), hope this will help you for detail see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

With data.name[0] you will get the name Enid Norgard
Similar to that use

```
data.name[index]
```

while index is the position of the name in the innerarray.

If you want only the names array use:

```
alert(data.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to loop through all elements

```
for(x in data)
{
    for(y in data[x])
    {
        alert(data[x][y]);
    }
}
```